# How to properly unmount a bind mount?

Tags: linux, mount, chroot, umount

In order to create a chroot, I often do something like:

```
mount --bind /dev ./dev
```

But when I try to unmount `./dev`, it sometimes attempts to unmount/redirect to `/dev` instead.

How to tell I want to unbind the mount and not the original mount point ?

Comment: *sometimes* makes it sound intermittent, anything unusual about those "some" times?

Comment: Sanity check. If your current working directory is `/`, then `./dev` is equivalent to `/dev`. If your current working directory is not `/`, then `./dev` is in general not equivalent to `/dev`. A simple explanation of the issue is you `mount` onto `./dev` in a non-root directory, but then sometimes you try to umount `./dev` while being in `/`. Can it be the case?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski even when I’m in `/tmp/chroot` this does it. Even asking to lazy unmount `/tmp/chroot/dev`in full path makes `/dev` to be unmmounted.

Comment: @JaromandaX impossible to understand. bind unmounting `./sys` will work while the exact same command with `./proc` will fail or vis versa. You can try yourself at that point.

Comment: I can try what at what point?

Comment: @JaromandaX bind mount `/dev` or `/tmp` to elsewhere and then fail to unbind the mount.

Comment: Oh, I've never had an issue with umounting such a mount